# External authentication providers and authenticating requests to RESTful API

Tags: node.js, rest, express, authentication, jwt

I'm working on adding google login to my web app. It's a RESTful app, so once a user is logged in, each individual request must be authenticated with a token.

Currently, I create my own tokens using JWT. I can add useful information to the token object to help with state management.

My question is: once I add google as an authentication provider, do I then need send every request to Google to be authenticated, rather than authenticating it on my own server? Do I then lose the ability to customize the content of the token?

With external authentication providers, is it normal to manage separate JWTs for calls to your RESTful API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'll have the login action use the third party to identify the user. Your internal code will probably create/store/fetch an app local user profile of some sort, and you'll create your JWT based on that. Further calls to your API bearing a valid token are then trusted to have already been authenticated and therefore need no further calls to the auth provider.

Comment: Thank you. I know this is a pretty general question, but sometimes there's a fog around certain topics that no amount of googling seems to clear up.